# Angular translate inside service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angular-translate

I am struggling with angular translate for my ionic app. The thing is that I have a service with data to share between views but I need to translate this data. Unfortunately I just see blank screen without any errors in console.

I would appreciate if someone could help if there is something wrong with that code (I use useStaticFilesLoader):

```
app.service('customService', function($q, $rootScope, $filter, $translate) {

    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {     
        var $translate = $filter('translate');                      

    return {
    items: [
      {
        id: '1',        
        title:$translate('TITLE');
      }
    ]
],
    getItems: function() {
      return this.items;
    },
    getItem: function(itemId) {
      var dfd = $q.defer();
      this.items.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.id === itemId) dfd.resolve(item);
      });

      return dfd.promise;
    }

 };
});
});
```

Comment: Just my 2 cents: by defining `var $translate;` you are overwriting the $translate provider injected in the service, which might cause problems. You should avoid using $ in your variable names altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
app.factory('customService', function($rootScope, $translate) {
    var items = [],
        updateItems = function() {
            items.length = 0;
            $translate('TITLE').then(function(title) {
                items.push({
                    id: '1',
                    title: title;
                });
            });
        };
    updateItems();
    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', updateItems);
    return {
        items: items,
        getItem: function(itemId) {
            var result;
            items.forEach(function(item) {
                if (item.id === itemId) {
                    result = item;
                }
            });
            return result;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. It is so strange but I am trying to use your first code and it seems that items: items, is just empty. Like the array is not filled on $translateChangeSuccess. Do you think it is possible to fix it?

Comment: is the `$translateChangeSuccess` event being captured? You should be able to put a break point in `$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function() { ... }`.

Comment: Yes, I believe. It just wont fill the var items = []; For example if i put something like var items = [1,2]; then 2 items show up. But keeping it blank no items returned even that we specifie them inside $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess'....

Comment: right... you probably need to `push()` the results to the item array

Comment: You were right. Pushing the array helped but title: $translate('TITLE'); return just brackets {}. The weird thing is that using $translate.instant shows us the translation fine. Would you recommend using it? I read somewhere that it is better to use filter first...

Comment: it appears as though $translate returns a promise. I will update my answer.

Comment: This is awkward but navigating to this list from home of my app shows the list empty but If I reload the page, the list shows up. What could cause this? Thanks for all your help, its amazing that you manage it so good!

Comment: It is probably just a race condition. The event is probably fired before the service is ready. Let me adjust the code.

Comment: Adding $translate.refresh(); before var items = []; helped to fix navigation. 
I still need to use  var $translate = $filter('translate'); Unfortunately  item.length did not help.
If you validate the use of transalte.refresh I can confirm that everything is just fine for now.